# How to properly structure a Multicolumn Index with a partial field search

Tags: postgresql

What is the best way to setup multicolumn index using the full_name column and the state column? The search will use the exact state with a partial search on the full_name column. The query will like this:

```
WHERE full_name ~* 'jones' AND state = 'CA';
```

Searching roughly 20 million records.

Thanks!

John

Answer (score 0):

The state seems straight-forward enough -- a normal index should suffice.  As far as the full name search, this is a lot of work, but with 20 million records, I think the dividends will speak for themselves.

Create a new fields in your table as a tsvector, and call it `full_name_search` for the sake of this example:

```
alter table <blah> add column full_name_search tsvector;
```

Do an initial population of the column:

```
update <blah>
set full_name_search = to_tsvector (full_name);
```

If possible, make the field non-nullable.

Create a trigger that will now automatically populate this field whenever it's updated:

```
create trigger <blah>_insert_update
before insert or update on <blah>
for each row execute procedure
    tsvector_update_trigger(full_name_search,'pg_catalog.english',full_name);
```

Add an index on the new field:

```
create index <blah>_ix1 on <blah>
using gin(full_name_search);
```

From here, restructure the query to search on the tsvector field instead of the text field:

```
WHERE full_name_search @@ to_tsquery('jones') AND state = 'CA';
```

You can take shortcuts on some of these steps (for example, don't create an extra field but use a function-based index instead), and it will get you improved performance, but not as good as what you can get.

One caveat -- I think the `to_tsvector` will split into vector components based on logical breaks in the contents, so this:

```
Catherine Jones Is a Nice Lady
```

will work fine, but this:

```
I've been Jonesing all day
```

Probably won't.

Comment: I don't think you actually need to add the `full_name_search` column to the table. You can create an index on `to_tsvector (full_name)` directly

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name --  I could be wrong, but I at one point I benchmarked the two, and it was noticeably faster when I made it a separate field.  It's possible this has changed with subsequent releases, and it's also possible I'm just wrong.

Comment: John -- I'd recommend you try both.  I'm anxious to see the difference if adding the field is worth it or not.